# Facebook Login in Google App Engine Application (Java)

Tags: java, facebook, google-app-engine

Currently, users of my appengine application can use their gmail account to login to the site. I want to allow users to login using their facebook account. How to do this?

Comment: Here is a post describing what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566988/java-example-how-to-login-with-facebook-account-on-gae-using-oauth/9580644#9580644

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woops, I did not read your post right, I think [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/) is what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want ?

[Google app engine: create a facebook app](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/shelftalkers?hl=nl-BE)

Comment: no, i just want users can login using their facebook account.